# How to render directory structure as text in Shiny?

Tags: python, pathlib, py-shiny

Developing an app that takes a directory path as input and reads all relevant files inside of it. I'd like for users to see what directory structure is expected before providing this path. The directory structure looks like this:

```
project/
├── Input/ # <- path user enters
│   ├── Group 1/
│   │   ├── Data Request Form/
│   │       └── DO NOT EDIT/
│   │       └── DRF.xlsx
│   │   └── Data/
│   │       └── Datasets 1/
│   │           └── *[.csv|.txt]
│   │       └── Datasets 2/
│   │           └── *[.csv|.txt]
│   │       └── Datasets 3/
│   │           └── *[.csv|.txt]
│   └── more groups ...
├── Output
```

How can I render this text as seen above in Shiny?

For reference, I am storing this as a string to be rendered in Shiny - this will not update to match the directory structure of the path provided.

Comment: If you already have this  text you can render it with `renderPrint` and `verbatimTextOutput`.

Comment: Thank you - for future readers using Python Shiny, `render.text` and `ui.output_text_verbatim` worked here.